# Difference between REST call and URL

Tags: web-services, rest, url, url-rewriting

I have been into web development from sometime. But recently came across an old technology, `REST`. I read various places about `REST` calls, what I have understood about `REST` service is,

- `REST` service responds back with `JSON` or `XML` data, which can be used on client side for rendering the DOM elements.
- It enhances the use of `HTTP` protocol.
- The URL difference between a `REST` call and normal `URL` is:

  **REST CALL**: `wwww.xyz.com/getCart/12`

  **URL**: `wwww.xyz.com/getCart.php?cartId=12`

I got the basic difference, hitting the URL would render a page at the server end and would return the response, whereas making an AJAX Call to the `REST` service would simply return a `JSON` or a `XML` output which can be parsed at the client end.

My **question** is:

If I make my `.php` page to render a `JSON` string, and the application makes a `AJAX` call to the `php` page to get the `JSON` response back and use it on client side to render the DOM, then what is the difference between `REST` call and a normal `URL` call.?

How `REST` calls are configured differently from normal `URLs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot of misinformation and confusion about REST. I'm not surprised that these three points are  what you understood from the information available, but they are wrong.

- REST isn't coupled to any particular data format or media type. The most important constraint in REST is the emphasis on an uniform interface, which means in this case that the server should be able to respond with whatever data format or media type the clients accept. Under HTTP, the client will tell what formats it can understand through the `Accept` header, and the server should comply or fail with a  `406 Not Acceptable` error.
- In the same way, REST isn't coupled to any particular protocol, although it's often convoluted with HTTP. Again, following the uniform interface, the clients should be able to follow any links provided by the server, for any protocol with a valid URI scheme.
- The semantics of URLs are completely irrelevant to REST. All that matters to REST is that an URL identifies one and only one resource. The URL is an atomic identifier and the client shouldn't rely on any semantics embedded in it for any operations. The two examples you give are both valid in REST. There's nothing more or less RESTful about any of them.

To answer your question, under a REST application the difference you imagine doesn't exist. Hitting an URL will return a response. If the client is requesting with an `Accept: text/html` header, it may return the human-friendly html page to be rendered by a browser. If the client requests with an `Accept: application/json` or `Accept: application/xml`, it may return a machine-friendly format to be read by another application.

Comment: I somewhat got your point. And I guess it is correct.. but is there any difference between configuring an application for REST and for URL?

Comment: There's no difference. It's the same thing. Every valid URL is also valid in REST, as long as it refers only to a single resource.

Comment: What I meant was, is there any difference between file structure of REST and normal URL.. how do we receice REST calls. I am sure that we do not have folder structure in the same way as we have the URL.

Comment: There's no such thing as a REST URL and a normal URL. The contents of an URL are irrelevant from a REST standpoint. You're seeing a distinction where there is none. There are conventions adopted for URLs in HTTP APIs, and I think that's what you mean by "folder structure". In that sense, then you can say /carts/12 is more REST-like than /getCart?id=12, but this is very subjective. People lose a lot of time in endless debates about this, but it's not that important. What's important for REST is how your clients obtain the URLs.

Comment: @PedroWerneck So when we enter a URL in the browser, does the browser automatically make a `GET` request with `Accept` header set to `text/html` so that the server is forced to return an HTML page? What happens if we enter a GET endpoint in the browser which sends a `JSON` response? How does browser still correctly display the JSON data?

Comment: @darKnight When you enter an URL in the browser it sends an `Accept` header with several different acceptable mimetypes and their weights, including `*/*` which makes any mimetype acceptable and displayed as text. You can read about that in the RFC 7231: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#header.accept

Answer (score 3):

REST is just an architectural style, there is no technical difference.

One of the things that REST defines is that your URL needs to be atomic identifiers that refer to only one resource.

> GET /users/:id  (return the user with the given :id)
>
> PUT /users/:id  (update the user with the given :id)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268933/do-i-need-a-framework-to-build-a-rest-api-in-php) is an answer about using a framework to make a REST API in php.

Comment: While I agree there is no technical difference, I disagree that REST defines anything regarding URL semantics other than being atomic identifiers that refer to only one resource. Having well-thought URLs is a good design practice overall, but it's not directly related to REST. Often, when people think URL semantics matters to REST, they are not using HATEOAS, which means they're not using REST at all.

Comment: You are right about it, was what i wanted to say with "need to be representative", but english is not my native language :/. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Rest puts more emphasis on the verbs, like `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`... You can call one method like

```
/api/Customers
```

and depending on the verb you use it will do a get, post, put or delete. You can also make more easy URL's like

```
/api/Customers/{id}/Orders/{id}
```

instead of making a method that would be

```
api/GetCustomersOrders?id=x&id=y.
```

Comment: I am aware of this part. But you can easily handle this part. Does it make any change in configuration of the application?
What I know Java takes care of this part while deploying the WAR file but how would you configure the same in php file.?

Comment: I am not really a PHP programmer, but this might help. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest--net-16340

Answer (score 1):

*All Web Services are APIs, but not all APIs are Web services.*

**APIs** are application interfaces, meaning that one application is able to interact with another application in a standardized way.

**Web services** are a type of API, which must be accessed through a network connection.

**REST APIs** are a standardized architecture for building web APIs using HTTP methods.