# Ember JS rest adapter and php files

Tags: javascript, php, rest, ember.js

so im looking at the ember js documentation, and im a bit confused about how to use the adapter here:

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/

Now it says, for example, that if I want to use the find method then,

"The REST adapter will automatically send a GET request to /photos/1."

But i don't understand how this url is supposed to trigger a php file to return some data. It looks like its trying to go to a file called 1 without an extension in the photos directory. So what would a php file look like (in terms of directory) which would be triggered by this? Does it somehow just figure out the extension in order to be generic to any rest endpoint? Any help would be greately appreciated.

I'm completely new to ember data so sorry if this a newb question.

It would be really nice if there was a simple example project that used php and ember together, but I've only found tutorials talking about the ember side.

Comment: I think your question is more about how to build a REST api with PHP. Using a PHP framework will help you go a long way. Maybe this SO answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268933/do-i-need-a-framework-to-build-a-rest-api-in-php. Keep in mind that with some apache rewrites `/photos/1` could actually point to, say, `index.php` and with `$_GET` params as `action=photos&id=1`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using ajax to build the backend is quite clear and sensible, but it seems like the built in rest adapter for ember is somewhat vague and the documentation is very sparse. I feel like the ember js website should have some example in node, php, etc just to give an idea of how to use the rest adapter. What kind of apache rewrites would I need to do? Also would I need to parse the url to get that data (id = 1)? It seems like it would just be easier to put ID in another post variable and go from there. Would there be any advantage to parsing the url?

Comment: It's very out of scope for EmberJS to document or guide us how to build our APIs. Whether the language is Node, PHP, Python or Ruby - Ember doesn't care. Find a separate tutorial for that. The RESTAdapter deals strictly with the data coming from the server and how it's formatted/structured. Look into using PHP frameworks such as Laravel or CakePHP to help you build your API. These will help abstract away URL rewriting or parsing from you. Or better yet, have a server-side dev build your API so you can focus on the front-end.

Comment: Well i realize that ember doesn't care about the rest end point but i don't tjo